URL changing but view is not changing in react router v6
So I have a create-react-app that was working previously off tabs in one page. But I want to modify it so that a home page has buttons linking to each tab hosted on different URL's being redirected by react-router v6.
I have the below code with a hashrouter in the parent component.
import './App.css';
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./components/Home"
import UciStandingsTabs from "./components/standings/UciStandingsTabs";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />}/>
            <Route path="/standings" element={<UciStandingsTabs />} />
          </Routes>
      </div>
    );
  };

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import {
  createHashRouter,
  RouterProvider,
} from "react-router-dom";

const router = createHashRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <App />,
  },
]);

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!);
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

The issue is that when you click each button that appears you can see the url change but the view itself is not changing.
Can anyone help me out as  I am not sure what I am missing here.
I am expecting to click link buttons and render a different component on the page. I had it all previously running in a tab format without react router so I'm inclined to believe its not an issue with components.
This question does not seem to resolve my issue as far as I can understand. I am following the docs of react-router and anything suggested in that answer still provides the same issue

I had found that before but exact is deprecated now and no longer used. I see in the docs where it is supposed to match everything exact by default but just don't understand what I am missing. Been trying to make it work based off of this and some other variations I found but it all seems to come to the same result

Your router seems to be incomplete, you should add children path in createHashRouter function. Read more in docs

thanks @SanketSapate between reading the docs more thoroughly I added those which was part of the problem but the biggest one was me accidentally using Link from @ mui instead of the react router Link.
